# Change inner text of icon with Jquery

Tags: jquery, materialize

I'am trying to change text nested inside an icon element with Jquery.

This is my icon element:

```
<i class="material-icons">report</i>
```

And I want to change the inner text to "report_problem" like this:

```
<i class="material-icons">report_problem</i>
```

This is what I have tried so far but it did not succeded:

```
$(.material-icons).innerHTML("report_problem");
```

Anyone has a clue?

Comment: Just as a heads up in case you solved your issue but didn't know why the above didn't work. `innerHTML` is a property on the DOM object accessed as such `$(.material-icons)[0].innerHTML`.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace Indeed i wanted someone to tell me why it didnt worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution. Both `.text` and `.html` work

```js
$('.material-icons').html("report_problem");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i class="material-icons">report</i>
```

Answer (score 2):

Already fixed this by using:

```
$(.material-icons).text("report_problem");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try this in something like the Google Debugger console, you'll see that "$(...).innerHTML is not a function"

As alluded to in a comment, that is a method on the DOM, but not in jquery.  That's why .html and .text do work (they are jquery functions) and .innerHTML did not.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you use classes and a toggle function, like

```
<i class="material-icons report-icon"></i>
```

in css you control the text:

```
.material-icons.report-icon{content:"report"}
.material-icons.report-icon.with-problem{content: "report_problem"}
```

and in the jQuery you can control when it changes with this functions

```
function toggleReportIcons(){
    toggleReportIcon($(".report-icon"));
}

function toggleReportIcon(reportIcon){
    $(reportIcon).toggleClass("with-problem);
}
```

and you can call this functions whenever you need to change the icon, either if is just one or all.